# C# CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found in asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have read all the similar posts here on stackoverflow and I'm still unable to resolve the issue.

These are my steps in Visual Studio 2015.

1. I create new project named "208" choosing Web -> ASP NET Web application (Net Framework)-> Empty
2. I right click on my project and choose Add -> New Item -> Web form
3. Just to test I create a new project in the same solution, a Class library solution and name it "MyClasses." Then I add a public class "Class1" with one public property.
4. I right click on the project "208" and add a reference to "MyClasses."
5. I add "using MyClasses;"
6. I build the project locally and it works fine.
7. I publish using FTP to my host and I get "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyClasses' could not be found..."

Both projects, "208" and "MyClasses" are built against Net Framework 4.6.1
The host has Net Framework 4.6.1

When published to the host, I can open the "bin" folder and I see the .dll file "MyClasses.dll" there.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

The dll file is there when I publish:

[image: dll]

Using added:

[image: using]

And the error (CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyClasses' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?):

[image: error]